# OpenMP taskwait not working

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp

In the following code, I have created a parallel region using the `#pragma omp parallel`.

Within, the parallel region, there is a section of code that needs to be executed by only one thread which is achieved using `#pragma omp single nowait`.

Inside, the sequential region their is a `FOR` loop which can parallelized and I using `#pragma omp taskloop` to achieve it.

After the loop is done, I have used `#pragma omp taskwait` so as to make sure that the rest of the code is executed by only one thread. However, it seems the is not behaving as I am expecting. Multiple threads are accessing the section of the code after the `#pragma omp taskwait` which is declared under the region defined as `#pragma omp single nowait`.

```
  std::vector<std::unordered_map<int, int>> veg_ht(n_comp + 1);
  vec_ht[0].insert({root_comp_id, root_comp_node});

  #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
            for (int l = 0; l < n_comp; ++l) {
                    int bucket_count = vec_ht[l].bucket_count();

                    #pragma omp taskloop 
                    for (int bucket_id = 0; bucket_id < bucket_count; ++bucket_id) {
                        if (vec_ht[l].bucket_size(bucket_id) == 0) { continue; }
                        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
                        for (auto it_vec_ht = vec_ht[l].begin(bucket_id); it_vec_ht != vec_ht[l].end(bucket_id); ++it_vec_ht) {
                            // some operation --code removed for minimality
                        } // for it_vec_ht[l]  
                    } // for bucket_id taskloop

                    #pragma omp taskwait 

                    // Expected that henceforth all code will be accessed by one thread only
                    for (int tid = 0; tid < nthreads; ++tid) {
                      // some operation --code removed for minimality
                    } // for tid
            } // for l
        } // pragma omp single nowait
    } // pragma parallel
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and describe precisely what you observe and how it differs from what you expect.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look like you necessarily need to use the enclosing parallel/single/taskloop layout. If you aren't going to specify the number of threads, then your system should default to using the maximum number of threads available. You can get this value outside of an OMP construct using `omp_get_max_threads()'. Then you can use just the taskloop structure, or just replace it with a`#pragma omp parallel for`.

I think the issue with your code is the `#pragma omp taskwait` line. The single thread should fork into many threads when it hits the `taskloop` construct, and then collapse back to a single thread afterwards. I think you might be triggering a brand new forking of your single thread with the `#pragma omp taskwait` command. An alternative to `#pragma omp taskwait` that *definitely* doesn't trigger thread forking is `#pragma omp barrier`. I think making this substitution will make your code work in its current form.

Comment: "The single thread should fork into many threads when it hits the taskloop construct, and then collapse back to a single thread afterwards. " Sorry, but NO. The taskloop does not create threads.It creates tasks which are executed by existing threads.

Comment: A `barrier` within a `single` region seems like a very bad idea.

Comment: If his taskloop wasn’t forking then he wouldn’t be seeing this problem. Right? Because he’s in a single structure already so this whole region starts off with just a single thread. The rest of his initial thread skip the region that’s producing the undesired behaviour.